# Angular 4 reusable add edit components

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 4 and working on forms(reactive forms).Here we are using same form component for both add and edit.For both create new and update i am using same function. So whenever we save the form, we are creating new instance and update all the fields with data.Here some of fields data are unique.For example,the created date and created by fields data should not be modified once saved new form.But here whenever i edit the form the both are updating.

formcomponent.html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <span translate>{{isEditMode ? 'Edit' : 'New'}} Measure Protocol</span>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form [formGroup]="Form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Title">
                        <span>Number </span>
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="number" formControlName="Number" id="Number" class="ex-full-width" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        <span>Name</span>
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text"  formControlName="Name" id="Name" class="ex-full-width" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="action-btns-wrapper text-left">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                  (click)="saveChanges()">
                <span translate>Save & Back</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

form.component.ts

```
        //#region import
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from 
         '@angular/forms';
        import { HelperService, PdfSetting } from 
         './../../../_services/helper.service';
        import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
        import { SelectItem, ConfirmationService,} from 'primeng/primeng';
        import { Options } from './../../../_models/options';
        import { BaseServices } from './../../kuba.services';
        import { MeasureProtocolService } from './../services/measure-
        protocol.services';
        import { MPClientUsers } from './../models/measure-protocol';
        import { MP } from './../models/measure-protocol';

        @Component({
              selector: 'measure-protocol-form',
              templateUrl: 'measure-protocol-form.component.html'
         })

        export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
           @ViewChild(ToasterComponent) toasterComponent: ToasterComponent;
           Form: FormGroup;
           clients: SelectItem[];
           mpClientUsers: MPClientUsers[];

           contracterId: number;
           kundeELId: number;
           isEditMode = false;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private FormService: FormService,
    private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
    private location: Location, ) {
    this.measureProtocolForm = this.fb.group({
        'Number': ['', Validators.required],
        'Name': ['', Validators.required]
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contracterId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.Id = this.route.snapshot.parent.parent.params['id'];
    let res = this.route.snapshot.data['edit'];
    if (res) {
        this.isEditMode = true;
        this.initForm(res);
    } else {
        this.initForm();
    }
}

/**Save form**/
saveChanges(){
    let mp = new MP();
    mp.Id = (this.contracterId) ? this.contracterId : 0;
    mp.Number = this.measureProtocolForm.value.Number;
    mp.Name = this.measureProtocolForm.value.Name;
    mp.ClientId = this.measureProtocolForm.value.ClientId;
    mp.KundeELId =  this.kundeELId;
    mp.CreatedOn = new Date();
    mp.CreatedBy = BaseServices.UserId;
    mp.Status = 1;

    if (mp.Id > 0) {
        mp.ModifiedOn = new Date();
        mp.ModifiedBy = BaseServices.UserId;
        this.FormService
            .updateId)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.toasterComponent.callToast();
                this.gotoBack();
            });
    } else {
        this.FormService
            .create(Id)
            .subscribe((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.toasterComponent.callToast();
                }
                this.gotoBack();
            });

    }
}

initForm(data?: any){
    let Number = '';
    let Name = '';

    if (data) {
        Name = data.Name;
        Number = data.Number;

        this.Form = this.fb.group({
            Number: new FormControl(Number),
            Name: new FormControl(Name)
        });
    }
}

gotoBack(){
    this.location.back();
}
```

}

model.ts

```
export class MP {
Id: number;
Name: string;
Number: number;
CreatedBy:number;
ModifiedBy:number;
CreatedOn:Date;
ModifiedOn:Date;
```

}

Comment: You're doing the opposite of what you want in your form.component. You are assigning date and createdBy properties in `if (mp.Id > 0) {` but it should be done in the else code block

Comment: the FormGroup class contain dirty and touched method that help you to know if your form has been updated... also rely on your id field to know if your form is for creation or updation